# extremely thin connection bar in tikz mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

When compiling the following MWE with pdflatex:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  small mindmap,
  concept color=OrangeRed,
  every node/.style={concept}
]

\node{root}
  [counterclockwise from=30]
  child[concept color=Orange] {
    node { child 1 }
    [counterclockwise from=-60]
    child { node{grandchild 2} }
    child { node{grandchild 3} }
    child { node{grandchild 4} }
    child { node{grandchild 5} }
  }
  child[concept color=Gold] {
    [counterclockwise from = 80]
    node {child 2}
    child { node{grandchild 6} }
    child { node{grandchild 7} }
  }
  child[concept color=Coral] {
    node {child 3}
    [counterclockwise from = 90]
    child { node{grandchild 8} }
    child { node{grandchild 9} }
    child { node{grandchild 10} }
  }
  child[concept color=LightSalmon] {
    node {child 4 }
    [counterclockwise from =160]
    child { node{grandchild 11} }
    child { node{grandchild 12} }
    child { node{grandchild 13} }
  }
  child[concept color=Orange!50!white] {
    node {child 5 }
    [counterclockwise from=220]
    child { node{grandchild 14} }
    child { node{grandchild 15} }
    child { node{grandchild 16} }
  }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The connection bar between `root` and `child 2` appears extremely thin:

[image: mindmap]

This does not seem to depend on the exact angle where the connection is done nor on the position of `child 2` in the sequence of children of `root` (and neither the nodes' labels nor the colors change anything). What is wrong there?

Comment: NB: I've uploaded a `png`, since, as mentioned in this [meta-question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7895/add-directly-a-pdf-image-from-overleaf-to-a-question-or-an-aswer-edit), uploading `pdf` seems impossible at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you swapped the order: `[counterclockwise from = 80]` needs to go after `node {child 2}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  small mindmap,
  concept color=OrangeRed,
  every node/.style={concept}
]

\node{root}
  [counterclockwise from=30]
  child[concept color=Orange] {
    node { child 1 }
    [counterclockwise from=-60]
    child { node{grandchild 2} }
    child { node{grandchild 3} }
    child { node{grandchild 4} }
    child { node{grandchild 5} }
  }
  child[concept color=Gold] {
    node {child 2}
    [counterclockwise from = 80]
    child { node{grandchild 6} }
    child { node{grandchild 7} }
  }
  child[concept color=Coral] {
    node {child 3}
    [counterclockwise from = 90]
    child { node{grandchild 8} }
    child { node{grandchild 9} }
    child { node{grandchild 10} }
  }
  child[concept color=LightSalmon] {
    node {child 4 }
    [counterclockwise from =160]
    child { node{grandchild 11} }
    child { node{grandchild 12} }
    child { node{grandchild 13} }
  }
  child[concept color=Orange!50!white] {
    node {child 5 }
    [counterclockwise from=220]
    child { node{grandchild 14} }
    child { node{grandchild 15} }
    child { node{grandchild 16} }
  }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Argl, how could I've missed that . Thanks for spotting it so quickly anyway (I'm not sure I want to know why putting the options before the node results in such a symptom while still putting `grandchild6` at the good place, though)

Comment: @Virgile This is because when `grandchild 6` is drawn, the angle is 80 regardless of the order. However, when the connection of `child 2` is drawn, the order is important because if you say `[counterclockwise from = 80]` too early Ti*k*Z has an incorrect angle for the connection. (At least I think that's what's going on.)